# I am having a problem with the grid and moving my div

Tags: html, css, css-grid

i have been trying to figure out how i can move one of my images to the left side of the screen but it is not working for me. i am pretty new to coding and if someone can help me, that would be much much appreciated!

this is my site: https://pagestoread.glitch.me/books1.html
(my codes are all over the place, so sorry for that!)

```
.books {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-column: 1fr 1fr;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.abundance {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
}

.before {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
}

.caraval {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}

.code {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}

.eragon {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: 4;
}

.family {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: 4;
}

.gatsby {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: 4;
}

.sister {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  grid-row-start: 3;
  grid-row-end: 4;
}
```

Comment: Where's the image? Where's the HTML? Please post enough code in the question to reproduce the problem.

Comment: It might be because the image and its description is out of the <table> markup. Check if that image is within the table markup... Or else your CSS is not getting applied to your images with grid property that you have written.